# SSO failing with Kerberos Authentication using apache. User is sent to ErrorDocument

Tags: authentication, centos, kerberos

I have a CentOS server running a Drupal, and its using the ldap module to provide SSO in to a domain, so users do not have to login.
I did not setup this and I had never used Kerberos, so I am really struggling here, even after reading how to set it up from scratch. I have no idea why it just stopped working. I did no changes to the setup, and the people managing the authentication controller/server claim they did no changes on their side.

Funny thing, we have other almost identical server which is still working properly. (They each have their own keytabs).

The vhosts.conf file for apache is like this:

```
   AuthType Kerberos
   AuthName "Intranet Login"

   KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM
   
   KrbMethodNegotiate on
   KrbMethodK5Passwd off
   KrbAuthRealms INTRANET.DDL.COM
   KrbLocalUserMapping on
   Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd/conf/intranet.keytab
   require valid-user
   ErrorDocument 401 /path/login-simple.php
```

When people try to access this site, they get prompted for user name and password, (Not drupal's, but apparently kerberos?) If they cancel, then they get sent to the ErrorDocument, where they are redirected to drupal and can login manually.

They didnt used to get this prompt.
The server where the keytab was originally produced, was shut down about 3 months ago, and just yesterday I started getting this issue. I am not even sure how it was still working. As far as I understand, it was just a domain controller, and they moved it to other server which provides the same service.
Yet...the other Drupal site, which has almost the exact same setup as this one, and also used to work with the old domain controller...IS working.

In the /etc/krb5.conf I changed the kdc, master_kdc, and admin_server to point to the new server that replaced the old domain controller. (But again, this was not needed in the other drupal site/server, and it is working, somehow)

Running klist on the keytab I get something like:

```
KVNO  Timestamp           Principal
____  ___________________ ___________________________
3     01/01/70 10:00:00   HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM
3     01/01/70 10:00:00   HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM
3     01/01/70 10:00:00   HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM
3     01/01/70 10:00:00   HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM
3     01/01/70 10:00:00   HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM
```

And running kvno HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM gets me

```
HTTP/intranet@INTRANET.DDL.COM: kvno = 3
```

Any help would be most appreciated. I just have no idea how to even debug this after working on it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the client's clock had drifted off for more than the 5 minutes tolerance for server-server authentication.

This was because the NTP server used by the client was decommissioned a few months ago, so the clock was no longer syncing.